# ActionMailer testing Email to Multiple Recipients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, actionmailer

Following the [RailsGuide Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), section on Sending Email To Multiple Recipients, emails are sent to the proper recipients from my app, however my rspec tests break.

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default to: Proc.new { Admin.pluck(:email) }
```

My rspec test looks like:

```
describe "Admin email" do
  let(:user)         { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
  let(:contact_form) { FactoryGirl.build(:contact_form) }
  let(:mail)         { AdminMailer.contact(contact_form) }

  it "renders the headers" do
    expect(mail.to).to eq([user.email])
```

The error message I get is:

```
Failures:

1) AdminMailer Admin email renders the headers
   Failure/Error: expect(mail.to).to eq([user.email])

   expected: ["joe@example.com"]
        got: []

   (compared using ==)
```

When I test in irb `Admin.pluck(:email)` works and it delivers email to the proper recipients, yet the test fails.  `Proc.new { Admin.pluck(:email) }` makes a proc object in IRB, instead of an array of emails.  I'm thinking the actuall mailer can deal with this but the rspec test can't.

Any ideas how I can test that the proper recipients are set in the email?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky but due to the order of operations of the mailer, you'll need to deliver the mail before the `to` is set.

```
 it "renders the headers" do
    mail.deliver_now
    expect(mail.to).to eq([user.email])
```

Comment: I get the exact same error message.  Previously I was not explicitly delivering the mail, is this something I should be doing?